# React native image contain

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-image

I want to fit an background image with full height and wdith,in contain mode but when i do the image height and width will get half
[![i got this result when i user resizemode="contain"][1]][1]
But when i use resizemode="cover" then image will cut from side like this
[![and in cover mode i got this result][2]][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tni5.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8IJT.jpg
I just  want something like that image just remain  in contain mode with full height and width

```
        <ImageBackground resizeMode="contain" source={{ uri: "https://www.anime-internet.com/content/images/2022/06/2022-06-07-23_09_28-AnimePahe_Tomodachi_Game_-_10_1080p_SubsPlease.mp4-VLC-media-player-1.jpg" }} style={{ height:"100%",width:"100%" }}>

        </ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

that cant happen . what you need to do is ask the designer to provide an image with the same dimension or aspect ratio.

Suppose you have an image with dimensions 60(height) * 100(width),

Then when you do styles like

```
<ImageBackground  resizeMode="contain" style={{width:200, height:120}} />
```

it will work since it fits the aspect ratio.

but `height :56 and width :99` will never be able to contain.

so whenver its the same aspect ratio it will worl

Feel free for doubts